# How to organize a list of structures based on an attribute

Tags: elixir

How can I organize this list of teams based on one of the numbers arguments of these structures?

```
defmodule Seeder do
    def start() do
        team1 = %Team{name: "Team ", points: "10"}
        team2 = %Team{name: "Team 2", points: "5"}
        team3 = %Team{name: "Team 3", points: "4"}
        team4 = %Team{name: "Team 4", points: "3"}
        team5 = %Team{name: "Team 5", points: "1"}
        team6 = %Team{name: "Team 6", points: "0"}

        result = calculate([team1, team2, team3, team4, team5, team6])
        IO.puts(result)
    end

    def calculate(teams) do
        teams
        |> Enum.map()
    end
end
```

Comment: What do you mean by "organize"? What's the output you want?

Comment: Organize from largest to smallest, for example.

Comment: What exactly is the input? You're assigning to variables that are ignored and calling Enum.map/1 which didn't exist.

Comment: I changed the code, so that it can be clearer

Comment: I think you're looking for `Enum.sort_by`: `Enum.sort_by(teams, fn team -> String.to_integer(team.points) end)`?

Answer (score 0):

thanks, @Dogbert.

```
defmodule Seeder do
    def start() do
        team1 = %Team{name: "Team 1", points: "1"}
        team2 = %Team{name: "Team 2", points: "5"}
        team3 = %Team{name: "Team 3", points: "10"}
        team4 = %Team{name: "Team 4", points: "3"}
        team5 = %Team{name: "Team 5", points: "1"}
        team6 = %Team{name: "Team 6", points: "0"}

        result = calculate([team1, team2, team3, team4, team5, team6])
        IO.inspect(result)
    end

    def calculate(teams) do
        teams
        |> Enum.sort_by(fn team -> String.to_integer(team.points) end)
    end
end
```